# QT Creator: OpenCV dll lib can not be added ("File format not recognized")

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I'm trying to get openCV 3.1.0 to work in QT Creator 4.4.1 using [this](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows) tutorial from their official site.

Right now, I'm setting up my project file. The whole file looks identical to the on in the tutorial apart from the last couple of lines, as my openCV build is in another place and it's a different version This is what I got:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\opencv\opencv-3.1.0\build\include

LIBS += -LC:\opencv\opencv-3.1.0\build\x64\vc14\bin \
    libopencv_world310d \
```

As far as I understand, the "world" module has been introduced to openCV to unify all the different modules into one.

However, when I try to run this, QT produces the following error:

```
C:\opencv\opencv-3.1.0\build\x64\vc14\bin\opencv_world310d.dll:-1: error: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

What am I doing wrong? In the tutorial there's an alternative way to link the libraries which even explicitly states them as .dll files. Why is this a problem?

Answer (score 3):

You need to link to the `.lib` contained in the `lib` folder:

```
LIBS += -LC:\opencv\opencv-3.1.0\build\x64\vc14\lib \
```

and put the `.dll` in the PATH, or the same folder of the `.exe`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer!
I changed "bin" to "lib" in my LIBS line and have my path variable referencing the /bin folder.
However, now I'm getting undefined reference errors for all my openCV references in my code. Do I need put every single dll in my PATH?

Comment: `-lopencv_world310`, not `-libopencv_world310`

Comment: I'm assuming you're referencing the LIBS line of my code. This is what it's looking like now:

`LIBS += -LC:\opencv\opencv-3.1.0\build\x64\vc14\lib \`
`-Lopencv_world310d \`

I'm still getting the undefined reference errors.

Comment: That should work, can you post the .pro you're using now?

Comment: [This](https://pastebin.com/gerc6Gy5) is my .pro, [this](https://pastebin.com/AFwfdx2L) is the sample code I'm trying to run (literally copy & pasted from the tutorial), [these](https://imgur.com/VjqbSOC) are the issues I'm getting. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Trying to run this with MSVC2015 64bit results in: _:-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'libopencv_world310d.obj'_

Comment: I don't see a problem with your Qt configuration. Regarding the other error it should not search for `libopencv_world310d`, but for `opencv_world310d.obj`. Be sure to use the correct VC14 is the compiler for MS Visual Studio 2015, so it should be ok

Comment: Turns out my mistake was using the "debug" build of MSVC2015 64bit instead of "profile" or "release". Those two work. It's fixed now, but thank you so much still.